# PHP não salva informações no MYSqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo um programa simples de cadastro, porém não sei por qual motivo os dados do Formulário não estão sendo salvos no Banco de dados (MYSQL).

Alguém pode consegue me dar uma ajuda nisso por gentileza??

Segue o Cógido:

```
<?php

include("conexao.php");

If(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nome", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cpf", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "senha", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nascimento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nascimento", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $cadastro = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cadastro", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $setor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "setor", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cargo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cargo", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $privilegio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "privilegio", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

If(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexão com o banco de dados, procure o administrador do sistema e informe o erro abaixo: ". "<br>" .mysqli_connect_error());
}

If(empty($nome)||empty($cpf)){
    echo "Preencha os campos corretamente!";
    exit;
} else {
    $sqlusuarios = "INSERT INTO TB_USUARIOS (nome, cpf, email, senha, nascimento, cadastro, setor, cadastro, privilegio) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$cpf."', '".$email."', '".$senha."', '".$nascimento->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$cadastro->format('Y-m-d')."', '".$setor."', '".$cargo."', '".$privilegio."')";
} If(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlusuarios)){
    echo "<script>Alert('Usuario cadastrado com Sucesso!');</script>";
} else {
    "Erro: " .$sqlusuarios. "<br>" .mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>DR3 WEB</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
                function mask_date(field){
                    if(document.getElementById(field).value.length == 2){
                        document.getElementById(field).value = document.getElementById(field).value + "/";
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById(field).value.length == 5){
                        document.getElementById(field).value = document.getElementById(field).value + '/';
                    }
                }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DR3 WEB</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Logout</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastros
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="empresas.php">Empresas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="clientes.php">Clientes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="fornecedores.php">Fornecedores</a></li>
                  <li><a href="estados.php">Estados</a></li>
                  <li><a href="municipios.php">Municipios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="usuarios.php">Usuarios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="classificacao.php">Classificação Financeira</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
</nav>
    <br>
    <h2>Cadastro de Usuarios</h2><br><hr><br>

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="usuarios.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="email">Nome:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome">
            </div>  
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">CPF:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">E-mail:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Senha:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Nascimento:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="nascimento" name="nascimento" onkeyup="mask_date(this.id);">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Cadastro:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="cadastro" name="cadastro" onkeyup="mask_date(this.id);">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Setor:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="setor" name="setor">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Cargo:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cargo" name="cargo">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="senha">Privilégio:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select type="text" class="form-control" id="tipo" name="privilegio">
                    <option value="1">Administrador</option>
                    <option value="2">Gerência</option>
                    <option value="3">Analista</option>
                    <option value="4">Assistente</option>
                </select>
            </div>

          </div>

          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" text-align=center>Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que erro te dá?

Comment: Não dá erro algum, apenas após clicar no botão cadastrar as informações somem do Form como se estivesse efetuado o Insert no banco, porém ao consultar no banco as informações não estão á, isso que é o mais estranho.

Comment: Muda os teus `If` para `if`, o PHP é case-sensitive.

Comment: Fiz essas alterações agora porém ainda assim não funcionou.

Comment: nos nomes das colunas no INSERT tem nome repetido `(nome, cpf, email, senha, nascimento, cadastro, setor, cadastro, privilegio)` duas vezes cadastro, axo q o segundo deveria ser `cargo`

Comment: Obrigado Léo, realmente estava incorreto este trecho do código, porém após eu corrigir ainda assim não grava no banco...continuo na mesma.

Comment: Altere esta linha `"Erro: " .$sqlusuarios. "<br>" .mysqli_connect_error($conn);` para `die(mysqli_error($conn));` e poste o resultado. Ficará mais fácil de alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado Andrei, o resultado do erro foi este - "Unknown column 'nome' in 'field list'", porém revisei o código e não encontrei nada incorreto.

Comment: Pessoal, resolvido aqui, na verdade eu estava fazendo besteira...na linha do Insert ao invés de informar o nome do campo no banco de dados, eu estava informando o nome do campo no formulario.

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda

Answer (score -1):

Sugestões:

- Adicione `die($sqlusuarios);` antes de chamar a função `mysqli_query` para ver se está montando o *SQL* corretamente.
- Olhe a diretiva do *PHP*, `display_erros` está habilitada.

Comment: Olá Everton, fiz conforme orientado e teoricamente o SQL esta sendo montado corretamente, veja resultado. INSERT INTO TB_USUARIOS (nome, cpf, email, senha, nascimento, cadastro, setor, cadastro, privilegio) VALUES ('Edson Luis Darezzo dos Santos', '30110986890', 'edarezzo@gmail.com', '123456', '1981-11-23', '2018-06-15', 'Desenvolvimento', 'Desenvolvedor', '1')

Comment: coloque no inicio do seu fonte este bloco e veja o que acontece quando executa. este bloco irá habilitar os erros do php por completo em tempo de execução 


ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Olá Everton, coloquei este bloco no inicio do código porém não me retornou nada.